# openssh - Reading from a file

Tags: linux, c, openssh

In the openssh code (openssh-5.9p1/auth2.c) in the function

```
input_userauth_request(int type, u_int32_t seq, void *ctxt)
```

I'm trying to read my own file (tried using `fopen`, `fread`) but `fopen` fails with an error saying `No such file or directory`. The file exists with full permissions. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked with a debug log statement immediately before your call to `fopen` that your filename supplied to `fopen` call is correct, i.e. includes the expected directory path?

Answer (score 0):

This function is called during in pre-authentication child (before authentication), which is `chroot`ed in `/var/empty/sshd/` (Fedora/RHEL). This is the reason why it can not find your file.

If you want it to find that file, you might disable `UsePrivilegeSeparation` option in `sshd_config` **NOT RECOMMENDED IN PRODUCTION!!!**. Read a bit more about [privilege separation in openssh](http://www.citi.umich.edu/u/provos/ssh/privsep.html).